# I try to view all the orders with the item & prices according to date chosen. It should show all the orders according to date but it only show 1 order

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

```js
function showData() {

    let count=0;
    let startdate = Date.parse(document.getElementById('startdate').value);
    let enddate = Date.parse(document.getElementById('enddate').value);
    const start = startdate;
    const end = enddate;

    document.getElementById("due").innerHTML = "";
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("orders")
      .where('order_datetime', '>=', start)
      .where('order_datetime', '<=', end)
      .get()
      .then((docs) => {
        docs.forEach((doc) => {
            

       if(doc.data().verified == 1){

       document.getElementById("due").innerHTML += `
                
       ${doc.data().productname}
       <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table table-striped table-borderless border-0 border-b-2 brc-default-l1">
                                <thead class="bg-none bgc-default-tp1">
                                    <tr class="text-white">
                                        <th class="opacity-2">#</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th>Qty</th>
                                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                                        <th width="140">Amount</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
            
                                <tbody class="text-95 text-secondary-d3" id="due">
                                    
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                                            `; 
                for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         
          document.getElementById("due").innerHTML += `
                                        <tr></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>${i}</td>
                                            <td>${(doc.data().items[i]["productname"])}</td>
                                            <td>${(doc.data().items[i]["price"])}</td>
                                            <td class="text-95">$10</td>
                                            <td class="text-secondary-d2">$20</td>
                                        </tr> 
        `; 
    } 
        }
        });
      });
  }
```

*I try to view all the orders with the item & prices according to the date chosen. It should show all the orders according to date but it only shows 1 order*

[![firestore][1]][1]

[![Output][2]][2]

firestore
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qum5c.png
output
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMxhl.png

Comment: Hi, did you check if there are more than one document between the mentioned start date and end date?

Comment: yes, there is more than one document (orders) between the start date and the end date. I want to display every order contain which is the items between those days. I'm not sure how to display it. Hope u can help with that

Comment: As it is JS, you need to follow a way to iterate,as shown in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) your current code is fetching one by one, then doing the fetch, so the collection of results is happening lower in the code, it should be higher. i.e. in between .where('order_datetime', '<=', end) and  .get() rather than at the end after the then((docs) line
simply, the iteration is in the wrong place.